# How to close socket when connection is lost during a blocking readline?

Tags: python, sockets

If you kill the server process on the server machine, the exception is caught on client and sys.exit() gets called. However, if the Ethernet cable on the server machine is pulled, the client forever remains in the readline... also, re-attaching the Ethernet cable resumes client/server communication!

EDIT: 
TCP is designed to work like this. Problem solved...

Comment: Yes - that is how TCP works.  It's a reliable protocol.   It can survive indefinite interruptions at the electrical layer if there is no attempt at communcation and quite long interruptions even if a comms attempt is made.

Comment: That's right, makes sense now.